# SQL Server query erroring with 'An object or column name is missing or empty'

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have the following query in a stored procedure in SQL server:

```
SELECT  TLI.LESNumber
    ,COUNT(TLT.PL)
INTO #PWCM
FROM #tmpLESImport TLI
INNER JOIN tbl_LES L 
    on TLI.LESNumber=L.NUMB
WHERE ISNULL(L.DELT_FLAG,0)=0
    AND L.SCHL_PK=@SCHL_PK
    AND TLI.PL IS NOT NULL
    AND LEN(TLI.PL)>0
GROUP BY LESNumber 
HAVING COUNT(PL)>1
```

When the query is run I get the following error:

`An object or column name is missing or empty. For SELECT INTO statements, verify each column has a name. For other statements, look for empty alias names. Aliases defined as "" or [] are not allowed. Change the alias to a valid name.`

Can anyone tell me why? `#PWCM` does not appear anywhere until this query.

Comment: You need to give `COUNT(TLT.PL)` a name

Comment: The table #PWCM doesn't appear before this because until statement execute it won't exist.

Comment: Oddly, this error also happens if you have syntax issues like a double-quote at the end of your SQL statement (could be a copy paste mistake)!

Answer (score 24, accepted):

When you `SELECT INTO` a table, it creates the table (in this case, a temp table). In order to create a table, each column needs a name, which your `count` column does not. You just need to give it a name:

```
SELECT  TLI.LESNumber,COUNT(TLT.PL) [NumRecords]
INTO #PWCM
FROM #tmpLESImport TLI
...
```

Comment: I  got bit by a different error ... in this case there was a monster subquery in an outer SELECT that threw the same error because I was replacing a string alias with AS syntax.  I didn't put the alias in the right place. :)

So I spent about 20 min on Google looking for a solution to my own typo ... this did not work well of course.

Where there are nested subqueries that need to be re-aliased to AS syntax so they'll upload on Azure ... beware the closing ')' some 3,000 lines after the opening (SELECT ...

Answer (score 11):

I had this error for this query

```
SELECT 
CASE WHEN COALESCE([dbo].[my-table].[field],"") = '...' THEN 'A' 
     WHEN COALESCE([dbo].[my-table].[field],"") = '...' THEN 'B' 
     ...
     END AS aaa  INTO ##TEMPTABLE
FROM [dbo].[my-table]
```

Turns out I had to change the `""` inside the COALSCE into `''`.

Solved it for me

Answer (score 0):

I just came across this, and the core reason was actually related to an errant set of brackets in the code which made the engine think there was a missing alias.  Something along the lines of:

```
select *
from SOME_TABLE
where x = 1
[]
```

A stringified version of the query included a parameter list for logging, but that was being issued as the query instead of the actual query object.  Deleting `[]` at the end resolved it.