# How to modify the input value of a stored procedure with python

Tags: python, sql, sql-server, python-3.x

Currently, I am trying to modify two input values of the following stored procedure that I execute with Python.

```
country_cursor.execute(
    "[DEV].[DevelopmentSchema].[QA_Extractor] @start_date='2017-05-05', @end_date='2017-05-11'")
```

I do not want to run this program every day and change the start_date and end_date manually from the code but instead trying to create a prompt where I can type down the dates that I want to look for the retrieval.

So far, I have done the following:

```
end_date   = str(datetime.now()).rpartition(' ')[0]
start_date = str(datetime.now() - timedelta(days=7)).rpartition(' ')[0]

country_cursor.execute(
    "[DEV].[DevelopmentSchema].[QA_Extractor] @start_date='2017-05-05', @end_date= "+"'"+end_date+"'"+"\"")
```

I just replaced one input date with a variable but when I execute this program I encounter the following SQL error:

```
pypyodbc.ProgrammingError: ('42000', '[42000] [Microsoft][ODBC SQL Server 
Driver][SQL Server]An object or column name is missing or empty. For SELECT 
INTO statements, verify each column has a name. For other statements, look 
for empty alias names. Aliases defined as "" or [] are not allowed. Change 
the alias to a valid name.')
```

My point of view is that the Stored Procedure does not accept this variable as the end date, in consequence, the column to look for the retrieval does not exist. I also read in [SQL Server query erroring with 'An object or column name is missing or empty'](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24998586/sql-server-query-erroring-with-an-object-or-column-name-is-missing-or-empty) which supports my view. Am I right with my thinking or am I totally wrong?

How can I fix this problem? Any ideas, suggestions and improvements are welcome ;)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I do this:

```
print("[DEV].[DevelopmentSchema].[QA_Extractor] @start_date='2017-05-05', @end_date= "+"'"+end_date+"'"+"\"")
```

I get this:

```
[DEV].[DevelopmentSchema].[QA_Extractor] @start_date='2017-05-05', @end_date= '2017-05-14'"
```

It seems to me that there is a stray `"` at the end of this query string.

Part of the problem is that you are working way too hard to format the dates as strings.

I am guessing that there is

```
from datetime import *
```

at the top of your code (ugly, but hardly your fault). If so, you can do

```
start_date = datetime.now() - timedelta(days=7)
end_date = datetime.now()
query_string = f"[DEV].[DevelopmentSchema].[QA_Extractor] @start_date='{start_date:%Y-%m-%d}', @end_date='{end_date:%Y-%m-%d'}"
country_cursor.execute(query_string)
```

which arguably makes it easier to see stray punctuation.